# Database schema design for stock market financial data

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql, finance

I'm figuring out the optimal structure to store financial data with daily inserts.
There are 3 use cases for querying the data:

1. Querying specific symbols for current data
2. Finding symbols current by values (e.g. where price < 10 and dividend.amountPaid > 3)
3. Charting historical values per symbol (e.g. query all dividend.yield between 2010 and 2020)

I am considering MongoDB, but I don't know which structure would be optimal. Embedding all the data per symbol for a duration of 10 years is too much, so I was thinking of embedding the current data per symbol, and creating references to historical documents.

How should I store this data? Is MongoDB not a good solution?

Here's a small example for a data for one symbol.

```
{
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "info": {
    "company_name": "Apple Inc.",
    "description": "some long text",
    "website": "http://apple.com",
    "logo_url": "http://apple.com"
  },
  "quotes": {
     "open": 111,
      "close": 321,
      "high": 111,
      "low": 100
    },
  "dividends": {
    "amountPaid": 0.5,
    "exDate": "2020-01-01",
    "yieldOnCost": 10,
    "growth": { value: 111, pct_chg: 10 } /* some fields could be more attributes than just k/v */
    "yield": 123
  },
  "fundamentals": {
    "num_employees": 123213213,
    "shares": 123123123123,
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 0):

> What approach would you take for storing this data?

Based upon the info (the sample data and the use cases) you had posted, I think storing the historical data as a separate collection sounds fine.

Some of the important factors that affect the database design (or data model) is the amount of data and the kind of queries - the most important queries you plan to perform on the data. Assuming that the JSON data you had posted (for a stock symbol) can be used to perform the first two queries - you can start with the idea that storing the historical data as a separate collection. The historical data document for a symbol can be for a year *or* for a range of years - depends upon the queries, the data size, and the type of information.

MongoDB's document based model allows flexible schema which can be useful for implementing future changes and requirements easily. Note that a MongoDB document can store upto 16 MB data maximum.

For reference, see [MongoDB Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Stock market data by itself is huge. Keep it all in one place per company otherwise you got a mess sooner or later.
your example above: logos are '.png' etc, not .html
your "quotes" section will be way too big ... keep it all on the top level... that's the nice thing with mongo. each quotes-document should have a date ;) associated with it... use a dateformat mongo also has, not a string for it...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33873476)